# Derivative of negative log gaussian

Tags: derivatives

I have a likelihood distribution $P(\mathbf{y}_i|\mathbf{W}) = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T + \sigma^2\mathbf{I})$

I want to maximize the total likelihood for all $\mathbf{y}_i$ by minimizing the negative log total likelihood which I got to

$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{W}) = \frac{ND}{2}\log 2\pi + \frac{N}{2}\log(\det(\mathbf{C})) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N(\mathbf{y}_i - \mu)^T\mathbf{C}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}_i - \mu)$

where $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T + \sigma^2\mathbf{I}$

In order to minimise this I need to get the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{W}$, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial W}$.

How do I compute this derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathbf{W}_0$ minimizes $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{W})$. If $\mathbf{Q}$ is some arbitrary matrix of the same dimensions as $\mathbf{W}$, then the function $f_{\mathbf{Q}}(t) = \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{W}_0 + t\mathbf{Q})$ will be minimized for $t = 0$ and — if $f_{\mathbf{Q}}'(0)$ is defined — have $f_{\mathbf{Q}}'(0) = 0$. This is valid for every $\mathbf{Q}$, especially for $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{E}_{ij}$, where the last matrix has zeros everywhere except on row $i$, column $j$, where it's 1.